# Separate axis labels on two axis in altair

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, altair

I am trying to use this code as an example to separate the axis labels for the y axis on the left and on the right side together.

```py
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "unique_ID": ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"],
        "group": ["Group 1", "Group 1", "Group 3", "Group 3", "Group 3", "Group 2"],
        "value": [20, 10, 30, 50, 40, 60]
    }
)
df

alt.Chart(df).mark_bar().encode(
    y="unique_ID",
    x="value",
    color="group",
)
```

What I would like to achieve is to use on the left side of the plot (i.e. where the axis labels for the variable `unique_ID` are) the labels of the variable `group` (without collapsing them into three bars) and on the right side of the plot (where I would usually put a secondary y axis) the values of `unique_ID`. Is it possible to do this in `altair`?

I understand that this is not really a secondary y axis because I am not using a different scale on both axes but instead would like to use that for styling purposes.

Thank you!

EDIT: @joelostblom thank you for your comment, I only used group in the color legend to indicate the other variable. What I would like to have is the following:

(sorry for still not providing a picture, upload is not working for ... some reasons I cannot tell due to missing error messages)

```
           ----------
Group 1    | xx     |   a
Group 1    | x      |   b
Group 3    | xxx    |   c
Group 3    | xxxxx  |   d
Group 3    | xxxx   |   e
Group 2    | xxxxxx |   f
           ----------

left       plotting     right
y-axis     area         y-axis
label                   label
```

So if you imagine this ascii art (who am I kidding) as a barplot, the x-es in the middle indicate the lengths of the bars. a-f on the right side are the axis labels of the variable `unique_ID` on the right side, and in addition I would like to have the labels also on a secondary vertical axis (on the left side) for the variable `group`.

I hope it is clearer now, and thank you very much for your help.

Comment: To clarify, `group` is encoded as the color legend in your example, are you saying that you want to move the legend to the left and the y-axis to the right? If not, could you make a mock up picture of the end result?